# How to display data by selecting respective option from drop down box in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

[image: Trying to display arts data by selecting "Arts & Culture" option from drop down box]

I am trying to display the data in the screen shot only when "Arts & Culture" option is selected from drop down box whose default value is " Choose Category". The code in my html is :

```
<div class="well">
    <h3>All Adventures</h3>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table>
    <tr><td>
    <select name="" id="" ng-model="category" ng-options="c for c in categories">
        <option value="">-- Choose Category --</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" value="Enter Current Location" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><select name="" id="" ng-model="tMode" ng-options="tM for tM in tModes">
        <option value="">-- Choose Transportation Mode --</option>
    </select></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
</div>

        <ul class="unstyled">
        <li ng-repeat="art in arts">
            <div class="well">
                <h4>{{art.name}}</h4>
                <h5><em>{{art.formatted_address}}</em></h5>
                <p>{{art.formatted_phone_number}}</p> 
                <p>{{art.vicinity}}</p>
                <p>{{art.types}}</p>                    
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

What changes in code must i make to make this work. I have been trying many examples on the web, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<li ng-repeat="art in arts" ng-show="category == 'Arts & Culture'">
```